# Drawing a image overlay on react-map-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to a floor plan layer with give coordinates on mapbox. I am using react-map-gl. (https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl). How can I draw a image overlay of on the map. Can you please quote some example or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can overlay an image using the `image` type of `source`. For instance:

```js
"sources": {
        "overlay": {
            "type": "image",
            "url": "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif",
            "coordinates": [
                [-80.425, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 37.936],
                [-80.425, 37.936]
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
```

From the example [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/).